# Java EE: Intercept server response to update session attributes

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have the following problem: I have a main menu bar at the top, and a (submenu) sidebar on the left. Now, these bars should have an active state, i.e. I want to mark them in an eye-catching way. In each state, each of the bar has one active marked item.

Instead of doing this is a JSP header, I want to do this based on the pageId of a session object. Thus, I need a mechanism to intercept each response and do a pageId-mapping like:

```
if (pageId=xy) {
  session.setAttribute("MenuBarActiveItemId", idX)
  session.setAttribute("SideBarActiveItemId", idY)
}
```

Is there a way to intercept all responses and perform such a mapping? Is this a useful way?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe a servlet filter can do the job.  Here's the Oracle docs: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html

Comment: This looks nice, I'm going to try that out! Thank you...